# rewrite incorrectly formated URLs with nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, get, url-rewriting

I have a script that creates a loop with certain links, like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php?print=1
http://example.com/index.php?print=1?print=1
http://example.com/index.php?print=1?print=1?print=1
http://example.com/index.php?print=1?print=1?print=1?print=1
```

I would like to have a rewrite (301 redirect) rule in place, that redirects any URL that contains ?print=1 more than once to the same url but with only one ?print=1

Example:

```
http://example.com/index.php?print=1?print=1?print=1?print=1?print=1?print=1
```

redirects to

```
http://example.com/index.php?print=1
```

and

```
http://example.com/somefolder/?print=1?print=1?print=1?print=1
```

redirects to

```
http://example.com/somefolder/?print=1
```

and

```
http://example.com/randomfilename.php?print=1?print=1?print=1
```

redirects to

```
http://example.com/randomfilename.php?print=1
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, nginx and regex/rewrites is still new to me...

Comment: well before we solve this we need to know how to detect it in nginx, is the word `print` the only word we need to check against? or is it an example word? and is there a possibility that another variable will be appended to it? for example `?print=1?print=1?print=1?new-variable=2` ?

Comment: It is not only the word print, but the entire string "?print=1" is used multiple times, no other GET variable is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not sure if this will work but we can try,

add these lines in the server block or the `location /` block

```
if ($args ~ "(print=1\?print=1)") {
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri?print=1;
}
```

Comment: perfect, worked with slight modifications. I updated your answer so it is the perfect solution for my issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok I checked what you edited, you have a point with `$args` not containing the first `?`, and since we're going to write `print=1?print=1` then we wont need the quantity `{1,}`, but I don't understand why replace `$request_uri` with `$uri`, and yes also for the `http`, but I prefer to use `$scheme`, I'll edit my answer with those 2 changes, try it sometime and tell me if it would work